# Assign IP to a VM from external DHCP server

Tags: mac, ip, dhcp, kvm-virtualization

When i install a new vm it fetches its IP from the DHCP server already setup when we install kvm. I am maintaining list of vm mac-addresses and there corresponding IPs (that should be assigned) in my external DHCP server. I want that vm to get its IP form the external server.
Anybody please list out the discrete steps required for the above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bridge networking and not the default one (NAT). The bridge should contain the external interface where your DHCP server is already running.